# Using Google Chrome extension APIs in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, typescript, webstorm

I'm building a Chrome extension written in TypeScript. I'm using [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm) and I added the `chrome-DefiniteltyTyped` library in my project.

However, when I wrote this in my TypeScript code:

`chrome.extension.getURL`

I got an error: `cannot find name 'chrome'`.

Because of this, my JavaScript file is not generated and I cannot use it in my extension.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That should work fine : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chrome/index.d.ts

TIP: make sure you have a `reference` tag added:

`/// <reference path="pathTo/chrome.d.ts"/>`

Comment: I recommend to install `npm install @typed/chrome`. There is no need for the reference path then (most IDE`s can resolve the types then easily).

Comment: doesn't work for me... when I call `chrome.storage` for example it is undefined... wondering if we have to add the permission somewhere...

Answer (score 92):

As of TypeScript 2 (or 2.x, not sure), you should import the Google Chrome types from @types.

In [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/):

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.35", // Or just npm install --save-dev @types/chrome
```

And in *tsconfig*:

```
    "types": [
        // (various types, e.g. jquery, core-js),
        "chrome"
    ]
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is a `devDependency` and not a regular one?

Comment: I think that if you intend to run typescript directly in the target platform (browser/node/etc), you should move the types dependency to production. Otherwise (which I think is the common case), the deliverable is the resulting js. Using the latter doesn't require the type definitions, they're needed only for type checking during ts transpilation.

Comment: How does it work? we have to type "import { Chrome } from '@types/chrome';"?

Comment: With these approach you don't have to import it explicitly. You can just reference `chrome` directly. If you use VS Code it should show up in IntelliSense.

Comment: I think you meant npm install --save-dev @types.chrome? --save will result in it being added to dependencies, not devDependencies.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: doesn't work for me... when I call `chrome.storage` for example it is undefined... wondering if we have to add the permission somewhere...  @argenkiwi thoughts?

Comment: 20 google searches later and I finally this answer, thank you so much Stuart.

Comment: Defining `types: []` in your `tsconfig.json` will actually _override_ all automatically detected types and is not the best practise. You should just have the `@types/chrome` package in your `devDependencies` (and locally installed in `node_modules/`) and TypeScript can automatically detect the types from your node_modules folder. Plesae see the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

Comment: I have `@types/chrome` as a dev dependency and everything's working so far except for the `InstalledDetails` interface. Anyone know if we have to do something extra to get this to work?

Answer (score 23):

### Types Across Chrome and Firefox

Since the extension API is basically the same across Chrome and Firefox now, you can use `@types/chrome` for both situations.

**1. install**

```
yarn add @types/chrome --dev
```

**2. update tsconfig**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....
    "types": ["chrome"]
  }
}
```

**3. Get browser api function**

```js
export function getBrowserInstance(): typeof chrome {
  // Get extension api Chrome or Firefox
  const browserInstance = window.chrome || (window as any)['browser'];
  return browserInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You just need to install **Type definition** to make it work. Let's install it:

```
yarn add @types/chrome --dev
```

Or NPM

```
npm install @types/chrome --save-dev
```

Now use it free of error!

Comment: Is there a way to use it with "npm -g install @types/chrome"?

Answer (score 6):

**Solution:** The [`chrome-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) is a package available through GoogleChrome's [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-types) repo and it has the type definitions for all chrome APIs so try using `chrome-types` instead of `@types/chrome`.

**Installation:**

```
npm install chrome-types
```

In **tsconfig.json**, add `"types": ["chrome-types"]` in the compilerOptions section.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["chrome-types"],
  },
}
```

Comment: This is actual answer! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the below error when trying to develop a Chrome extension using TypeScript in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and all I had to do was simply run:

`npm install --save-dev @types/chrome`

This will enter *"[@types/chrome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome)": "0.0.120"* under *"devDependencies"* in your *package.json* file.

Fixed error:

> [tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\my_user\Documents\my_chrome_extension\src\content.ts(28,3)
>       TS2304: Cannot find name 'chrome'.

Answer (score 2):

**What did work:**

Have TypeScript ignore the offending code by adding a comment like this above it.

`// @ts-ignore: saying 'chrome' is not found`

**What didn't work:**

- I had @types/chrome installed when I ran into this issue.
- In the *tsconfig.json* file, adding "chrome" under types and specifying the typesroot.
- Adding a reference path comment and all sorts of ways to
  import "chrome".

*Try these before you add the @ts-ignore comment.*

**Background:**

I am working on a Chrome extension using Angular 11. I need to access *chrome.runtime.sendMessage* to send information to a background worker.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have @types/chrome installed. I don't think you need to update the types and the typeroots of tsconfig. Then use the type definitions from chrome by accessing the chrome type which will be globally available, for example:

```
type getUrl = typeof chrome.runtime.getURL;
```

[image]

[A bit more context in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/51454)

Answer (score 1):

For manifest v3

"types" should be added in *tsconfig.app.json* instead of *tsconfig.json*,

[Use](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/development-basics/#types) `npm i chrome-types`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["chrome-types"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/background.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this happen to me too in Visual Studio Code.

I have a TypeScript project in subdirectory, i.e.:

```
project
|-> TS_folder
|-> non-TS_folder
```

And despite having `@types/chrome` installed, I've been getting the same error.

Luckily, I've noticed that Visual Studio Code just don't locate my `tsconfig.json` in the subdirectory. When I opened `/project/TS_folder` directly, i.e., having `TS_folder` be the root for the Visual Studio Code window, all the errors went away.

Screenshot of Visual Studio Code missing `tsconfig.json`:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code missing tsconfig.json]

Unfortunately, in Visual Studio Code, it being the super-customizable editor, there isn't any way to explicitly specify the path to your `tsconfig.json`. [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463) had a lot of traction, but it has been locked for quite some time now.