# Access to chrome extension through angular2 and typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

Trying to do an chrome extension with angular2 and typescript, I am stuck in how to get access to the chrome API (chrome.bookmarks in particular).

I do have access to the chrome object by following [angular2 chrome extension chrome.runtime.sendMessage from typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195654/angular2-chrome-extension-chrome-runtime-sendmessage-from-typescript)

But even though I can access to chrome, I cannot to chrome.bookmarks

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "x",
    "short_name": "x",
    "description": "x",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": "x",
    "permissions": [
        "bookmarks",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ]
}
```

And then, it seems that I should be accessing chrome through @types as suggested here
[Using chrome extension apis in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844406/using-chrome-extension-apis-in-typescript)

But I can't find how. Should I import what? `import { Chrome, filesystem, filewriter } from '@types';` ? I'm lost here, and I cannot find documentation about that (what makes me believe it is not a good idea to use angular2 for a chrome extension)

Comment: do show us how and fro. where (backround I hope) you are tring the bookmarks call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chrome` service is made available to your app at run time (when in the browser), and you don't have (or actually can't import it). What worked for me was to declare a var to avoid compilation errors:

```
declare var chrome;
```

and then in each code segment that deals with chrome, to first check if it exists (to avoid dev time crashes):

```
funcThatUsesChrome(args) {
   if(chrome){
      chrome.doSomeAction();
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean when in the browser as an extension? Because the app does run in a browser (localhost:3000). And, what's the way to user @types/chrome?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Chrome is available only when your app is ran as an extension. I'm not familiar with the @types/chrome solution.